# Derive Month to Date (MTD) from Year to Date (YTD) numbers in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below table with YTD numbers, every month (cumulative). I need to derive MTD numbers by deducting the prior month numbers from the later month numbers. Every month the numbers keep on adding. January numbers should remain the same becoz MTD and YTD numbers are same for Jan.Thanks for your help.

[image: df1]

Expected Result:

[image: df2]

Comment: you need to 201902_XYZ substract from 201901_XYZ and 201902_XYZ1 substract from 201901_XYZ1 and so on... do I understand the question correctly?
if it is right then just concatenate these two cell and do processes

Comment: Column0 is string and no calculation is required. The Jan numbers should get deducted from Feb and Feb should get deducted from March and so on Till dec. Since the year is on going i have numbers till Feb. But next month March numbers are going to be added to the list.

Comment: you can have unique values by joining date and Column0 for further calculations
please share the code that u have done so far

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

If there same values in `Column0` for each `MTH` groups, use:

```
df.iloc[:, 2:] = df.iloc[:, 2:].groupby(df['Column0']).diff().fillna(df)
```

If not, use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
g = df.groupby('MTH').cumcount()
df.iloc[:, 2:] = df.iloc[:, 2:].groupby(g).diff().fillna(df)
```